# How to communicate between two siblings components without changing state of parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I faced the following problem - I have `Parent` component, and two child components - `List` and `Map`. Both of these has children items. What I want is when I hover a component in `Map` - change style of appropriate component in `List` and vice versa.
I can handle hover events, but if I save ID of hovered element in `Parent` state, it will rerender full `Parent` component on each hover. How can I avoid this?
I'm not using Redux or something like this.

Comment: Are you sure it's a big problem to update the state of the parent component? If it contains many other children, you could consider making an intermediate component that only contains `List` and `Map` and update the state of that component instead.

Comment: @TomFenech, I'm not sure. I have list that can contain up to 1000 elements, and they are filtering and sorting before each `Parent` render, so I thouht it will not a good idea to rerender on each element hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it won't.**

---

It will only rerender the elements that have changed.
Just do it and don't worry - `O(n)` is **extremely** fast. 
As pointed out in the comments, if your component is extremely large - you could implement an intermediate one as well.

Here is how [React implements the diff algorithm.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html)

Rerender in case of:

- Different Node Types
- Key attribute changed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try test it on max amount of elements, but сonsidering not just render, but sorting and filtering and it will `O(n^2`) if I right

Comment: so if your complexity is quadratic anyways, you shouldn't worry about linear computations, at all.

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve communication between sibling components is via the state of a common parent.

If the state of the parent is updated, then it will re-render. If this is in expensive operation, then one solution would be to store the state in an intermediate component:

```
<Parent>
  <Intermediate>
    <Map />
    <List />
  </Intermediate>
</Parent>
```

Now the heavy lifting can be done in the `Parent` component and the result can be passed as props to the `Intermediate` one. When the state of `Intermediate` is updated, `Parent` doesn't have to do any work.